# Don't know how to display a new column in neo4j console

Tags: java, console, neo4j

I really need your help. Indeed, I want to display few columns in my neo4j browser. My developpment is based on **rabbithole project** which is developped by Michael Hunger.
I made some modifications in java code in order to add other few columns to my neo4j console. I don't know exactly where in the code of this project I can display the new columns. In other words, I want to display new rows with an additionnal column.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean.

The columns are shown automatically from your result query.

If you want to show rows that are note related to the cypher results you have to look in cypher.datatable.js